# Converting for loop in R to Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, loops, rcpp

I've been playing around with using more efficient data structures and parallel processing and a few other things. I've made good progress getting a script from running in ~60 seconds down to running in about ~9 seconds.

The one thing I can't for the life of me get my head around though is writing a loop in Rcpp. Specifically, a loop that calculates line-by-line depending on previous-line results and updates the data as it goes.

Wondering if someone could convert my code into Rcpp that way I can back-engineer and figure out, with an example that I'm very familiar with, how its done.

It's a loop that calculates the result of 3 variables at each line. Line 1 has to be calculated separately, and then line 2 onwards calculates based on values from the current and previous lines.

This example code is just 6 lines long but my original code is many thousands:

```
temp <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 2.211, 2.345, 0, 0.8978, 1.0452, 1.1524, 0.4154, 
                 0.7102, 0.8576, 0, 0, 0, 1.7956, 1.6348, 0, 
                 rep(NA, 18)), ncol=6, nrow=6)
const1 <- 0.938

for (p in 1:nrow(temp)) {
  if (p==1) {
    temp[p, 4] <- max(min(temp[p, 2], 
                          temp[p, 1]),
                      0)
    temp[p, 5] <- max(temp[p, 3] + (0 - const1), 
                      0)
    temp[p, 6] <- temp[p, 1] - temp[p, 4] - temp[p, 5]
  }
  if (p>1) {
    temp[p, 4] <- max(min(temp[p, 2], 
                          temp[p, 1] + temp[p-1, 6]),
                      0)
    temp[p, 5] <- max(temp[p, 3] + (temp[p-1, 6] - const1),
                      0)
    temp[p, 6] <- temp[p-1, 6] + temp[p, 1] - temp[p, 4] - temp[p, 5]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance, hopefully this takes someone with Rcpp skills just a minute or two!

Comment: If you want to run this faster, might it make sense to just move the first if outside the loop and run for (p in 2 :... ) ? I'm assuming you matrices are bigger then shown here. Saves you two checks per loop.

Comment: Thanks yes good point, this is a cheap and nasty sample code but I have done:
for (p in 1:1) {}
and
for (p in 2:rowslength) {} in my main code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an the sample Rcpp equivalent code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix getResult(NumericMatrix x, double const1){
  for (int p = 0; p < x.nrow(); p++){
    if (p == 0){
      x(p, 3) = std::max(std::min(x(p, 1), x(p, 0)), 0.0);
      x(p, 4) = std::max(x(p, 2) + (0.0 - const1), 0.0);
      x(p, 5) = x(p, 0) - x(p, 3) - x(p, 4);
    }
    if (p > 0){
      x(p, 3) = std::max(std::min(x(p, 1), x(p, 0) + x(p - 1, 5)), 0.0);
      x(p, 4) = std::max(x(p, 2) + (x(p - 1, 5) - const1), 0.0);
      x(p, 5) = x(p - 1, 5) + x(p, 0) - x(p, 3) - x(p, 4);
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

A few notes:

- Save this in a file and do `Rcpp::sourceCpp("myCode.cpp")` in your session to compile it and make it available within the session.
- We use `NumericMatrix` here to represent the matrix.
- You'll see that we call `std::max` and `std::min` respectively. These functions require two common data types, i.e. if we do `max(x, y)`, both `x` and `y` must be of the same type. Numeric matrix entries are `double` (I believe), so you need to provide a `double`; hence, the change from `0` (an int in C++) to `0.0` (a double)
- In C++, indexing starts from 0 instead of 1. As such, you convert R code like `temp[1, 4]` to `temp(0, 3)`
- Have a look at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html for more information to support your development

Update: If `x` was a list of vectors, here's an approach:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List getResult(List x, double const1){
  // Create a new list from x called `res`
  Rcpp::List res(x);
  
  for (int p = 0; p < x.size(); p++){
    // Initiate a NumericVector `curr` with the contents of `res[p]`
    Rcpp::NumericVector curr(res[p]);
    if (p == 0){
      curr(3) = std::max(std::min(curr(1), curr(0)), 0.0);
      curr(4) = std::max(curr(2) + (0.0 - const1), 0.0);
      curr(5) = curr(0) - curr(3) - curr(4);
    }
    if (p > 0){
      // Initiate a NumericVector `prev` with the contents of `res[p-1]`
      Rcpp::NumericVector prev(res[p-1]);
      curr(3) = std::max(std::min(curr(1), curr(0) + prev(5)), 0.0);
      curr(4) = std::max(curr(2) + (prev(5) - const1), 0.0);
      curr(5) = prev(5) + curr(0) - curr(3) - curr(4);
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This will give me something to sink my teeth into on Monday!

Comment: @Greg I have updated the answer with an approach

Answer (score 1):

So I tried both jav's answers, and did a little bit of reading. Looks to me like Lists are a R-kinda-thing and Rcpp seems to prefer simple vectors and matrices and whatnot.

So I decided to pass my vectors from the list directly into the Rcpp script. The whole thing works wonders. My ~70 second script which I got down to about ~5 seconds with parallel processing is now running in **0.3 seconds**. So Rcpp is pretty awesome at this as I had read.

Here's the code I went with:

(temp is a list of 3 vectors that feed into the calculation of the other 3 vectors, and that const 1 is a constant defined earlier in the code)

R code that calls the script:

```
temp <- getResult(zero=temp[[i]][, 1], 
                  one=temp[[i]][, 2],
                  two=temp[[i]][, 3],
                  const1=constant, rows=(as.double(rowslength)))
```

Output is a matrix with 3 columns calculated by the following Rcpp script:

#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix AWBMgetResult(NumericVector zero, NumericVector one, 
                        NumericVector two, double const1, double rows){
  // create numericmatrix x
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix x(rows, 3);
  // compute loop
  for (int p = 0; p < rows; p++){
    if (p == 0){
      x(p, 0) = std::max(std::min(one(p), zero(p)), 0.0);
      x(p, 1) = std::max(two(p) + (0.0 - const1), 0.0);
      x(p, 2) = zero(p) - x(p, 0) - x(p, 1);
    }
    else{
      x(p, 0) = std::max(std::min(one(p), zero(p) + x(p - 1, 2)), 0.0);
      x(p, 1) = std::max(two(p) + (x(p - 1, 2) - const1), 0.0);
      x(p, 2) = x(p - 1, 2) + zero(p) - x(p, 0) - x(p, 1);
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

I went with if else in the Rcpp code because I couldn't find out how to do 2 loops in a row, 1 of for (p in 1:1) and 1 of for (p in 2:rowslength). But it doesn't seem to matter from a speed point of view. I assumed an if else would still be quicker than an if = 1, if > 1 (since that is checking the value of p at every row)